# Set Default path for binary field

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, odoo-11

In odoo, I'd like to set a default path when upload a binary fields, for example when I upload a file the path should be always : "/home/user1/Documents".

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, please try to set `data_dir` (like `data_dir = /path/you/want`) in odoo-server.conf file. Or, you can set odoorc.conf file in home folder.

Comment: It doesn't work, after restarting the server. Odoo can't load